# Show that the tensor $(x+2)\otimes( x+2) -x\otimes x -2\otimes 2\in \langle x, 2\rangle^{\otimes 2}$ isn't pure

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, tensor-products

I'm trying to show that if $\iota\colon \langle x,2\rangle \hookrightarrow \mathbb{Z}[x]$, $P\mapsto P$ is a $\mathbb{Z}[x]$-linear injective mapping, then $\iota \otimes \iota$ isn't injective.

So, $\langle x,2\rangle \otimes \langle x,2\rangle\to \mathbb{Z}[x]\otimes \mathbb{Z}[x]\simeq \mathbb{Z}[x]$ may be seen as $P\otimes Q\mapsto PQ$ continued by linearity.

Let's try to check non-injectivity straightforward, i.e. $4\otimes x\mapsto 4x$ as well as $$\left ((x+2)\otimes( x+2) -x\otimes x -2\otimes 2\right) \mapsto 4x. $$

I want to believe that the second one isn't a pure tensor which proves the statement.

P.S. Is there a good way to explicitly evaluate $\langle x,2\rangle ^{\otimes 2}$?

Comment: On the third line the isomorphism should read $\mathbb Z[x]\otimes\mathbb Z[x]\cong\mathbb Z[x,y]$. In this case pure tensors correspond to products $f(x)g(y)$. Your element is $2x+2y$, so is not pure.

Comment: It's tensoring over $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, not over $\mathbb{Z}$. Be careful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are tensoring over $\mathbb Z[x]$, you can start with a projective presentation of your ideal
$$ \mathbb Z[x]\to\mathbb Z[x]^2\to(x,2)\to0.$$
The left hand map sends $r$ to $(2r,-xr)$, and the middle map sends $(p,q)$ to $xp+2q$. Exactness follows since we are in a ufd, so if $xp+2q=0$, then $2$ divides $p$ and $x$ divides $q$, and so $p=2r$ and $q=-xr$ for some $r$.

Now tensor this (on the right) with $(x,2)$ to get the exact sequence
$$ (x,2)\to(x,2)^2\to(x,2)\otimes(x,2)\to0.$$
Again, the map on the left sends $r$ to $(2r,-xr)$, and the map in the middle sends $(p,q)$ to $x\otimes p+2\otimes q$.

Your question is now whether $4\otimes x=2\otimes x+x\otimes 2$, equivalently whether $x\otimes2-2\otimes x$ is zero. Well, it comes from $(2,-x)$ in the middle, which is not in the image of the left hand map: there is no $r\in(x,2)$ with $2r=2$. Thus the element is not zero.